# Highstock - "destroy is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highsoft [HighStock](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock) to display a graph of trending data. The graph works great when the data is first loaded, but as soon as a change is made - using either the [`Series` object's](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#series-object) `setData()` or `addPoint()` functions - there are always errors along the lines of `oldData[i].destroy is not a function`. I even got the error [when playing with their JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.6/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/stock/samples/stock/members/series-addpoint/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[After reading a bit on the Highsoft support forums](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=11527#p54143), I discovered that Highcharts has a few different versions of HighStock floating around; I downloaded [a newer version of Highstock from github](https://raw.github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/stock2/js/highstock.src.js) instead of the version on their website, and all my problems were solved.